# what coule be request type for express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, file-upload

I try to upload a file in the node js application
Usually I use express.Request as request and express.Response for response

But If i use that the file is not accusable

```
app.post('/upload', function(req: express.Request , res : express.Response) {
   console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
});
```

with this, if I try access files like, It gives me error

```
req.files
```

I do not want to use **: any**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [@types/express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express-fileupload), it should provide the missing type declarations

```
npm i -D @types/express-fileupload
```